# how to add <script> tag dynamically in phpbb3 teamplate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, phpbb3

I am using phpbb3 as my board solution , i have already made the content pages etc .. all using integration with phpbb , now i want to add code from google adsense to my pages .. to do that i used the following script in overall_header.htm file in phpbb3/styles/prosilver/templates

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("<!-- INCLUDE ad.html -->").insertAfter(".column1 > ul");
    $("<!-- INCLUDE ad.html -->").insertAfter(".column1");
    });
    // ]]>
    </script>
```

where i have the add code in ad.html , and the selectors are such to put the code into proper place.

but somehow phpbb reads this as XML , and instead of executing the script , it show it in text.. and also execute the "" part and show the ads where i placed the script.

http://tutorialfrenzy.com/how-to-block-a-website.php

you can see it there. 
i tried using

```
         <script type="text/javascript">
         // Use any event to append the code
          $(document).ready(function() 
         {
          var s = document.createElement("script");
          s.type = "text/javascript";
          s.src = "http://scriptlocation/das.js";
         // Use any selector
         $("head").append(s);
        });
```

it didn't helped .. Any suggestions ?

EDIT:

Also i used jquery getscript method

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $.getScript("chitikaad.js", function(){
   alert("Running test.js");
   });
    </script>
```

Comment: 2 things.  What actually happened, and have you tried [jQuery.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)?

Comment: yes , i hv tried to use it ... still dont works , and it is shows error in console .. some ILLEGAL character thing

Comment: Can you post the error so we can see exactly what it is?

Comment: i m getting no error now ,idk why .. but it is not working also , i can't see the cod4 added anywhere at all , i can see the alert though

Comment: If you use `getScript()` you won't see the code - it doesn't add it to the head.  If you're not getting any errors then you at least know your included script doesn't cause any, which is a start.  Get rid of the alert in the callback function and put it in the js file you are loading.  At least that way you can see if it does actually run.

Comment: My included script works , i used an alert in the external .js called .. it shows up .. but still the code is not added to the end of .collumn1 div
thanks for helping

Comment: I can now see that <!-- INCLUDE ad.html --> is added to the html in elements in chrome , but it doesnt load the actual ads.hmtl file from the templates folder ... it just shows <!-- INCLUDE ad.html --> it is not replaces by the actual templeate ad.html

Comment: I've added an answer.  That should be what you're looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, the includes don't work in the js file.  Try changing it to this instead...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "ad.html",
        success: function(data) {
            $(data).insertAfter(".column1 > ul");
            $(data).insertAfter(".column1");
        }
    });
});
```

You don't need `<script>` tags when using `$.getScript()`, and `document.ready()` may not be needed, but it does no harm and since I haven't seen your whole project it's better to have it than not have it (it does run the code, even if the document had already loaded previously.)

Incidentally, if you can add script to the main page, then you don't need `$.getScript()`.  Just include the above script in the main page and it will load ad.html for you.  Obviously if there's any other code in chitikaad.js then carry on loading it as you are.